# Haskell function that returns sublists of a list

Tags: list, haskell

I'm writing a function in Haskell that, when given a list of numbers, will return a list containing all sublists (in order) of that original list. What I have so far is:

```
sublists [] = [[]]
sublists (x:xs) = [x:sublist | sublist <- sublists xs] ++ sublists xs
```

The above code, if given `[1,2,3]`, returns `[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,3],[1],[2,3],[2],[3],[]]`, which is not quite what I am looking for. Instead the function should return:

```
[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
```

How do I modify the given code to get this result?

Comment: `import Data.List` and `inits [1,2,3]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you take the first `n` elements from the list for `n` between 1 and the length of the input?

```
sublists :: [a] -> [[a]]
sublists xs = [ take n xs | n <- [1..length xs] ]
```

```
> sublists [1,2,3]
[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
```

Alternatively using recursion and pattern matching

```
sublists' :: [a] -> [[a]]
sublists' xs = sublist [] xs where
    sublist a [b] = [ a ++ [b] ]
    sublist a (b:bs) = [ a ++ [b] ] ++ sublist (a ++ [b]) bs
```